# Positioning for Isotope items

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-masonry, jquery-isotope

I just set up isotope for a recent project and added this at the bottom of my page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#isotope').isotope({
layoutMode : 'masonry',
itemSelector : '.isotope-item'
});
</script>
```

However, it doesn't work. All my items are shown one under the other. This is what I get on the .isotope-item divs. Only a vertical positioning is placed, no horizontal one.

```
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 1103px, 0px)
```

I'm trying to figure out what this is and would appreciate any help.

Comment: Whats the width of the containing element? And does it have `position: relative` set?

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't put this in. It is this: "position: relative; overflow: hidden; height: 4043px;".

Comment: And what is this elements width? Are you using firebug or similar?

Comment: The width is 1040px. I'm using Inspector in Chrome.

Comment: Did you set a width and height to your items ?

Comment: They all have different widths but no heights.

Answer (score 1):

Masonry layout in isotope uses the width of the first item by default. If this is more than half the container width they will all appear in one column.

Try setting the width to a small number as a test:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#isotope').isotope({
  layoutMode : 'masonry',
  masonry: {
      columnWidth: 5
  }
  itemSelector : '.isotope-item'
});
</script>
```

The downside of a very small `columnWidth` number is that isotope creates more columns for height calculation, which is slower and uses more memory.